# How can I enable Google's voice recognition?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, voice-command, archos-gen8, voice-recognition

I want to enable Android's Voice Input on my Archos 70 Internet Tablet.  Voice Input/Output isn't even visible in the settings menu.  Is there an apk file to add this or some other way?  I'm happy to take 3rd party Voice Recognition suggestions like vlingo if they don't need access to the Google Voice Recognition Engine, but I'm most interested in getting the standard Android voice input working.

***Device:** Archos 70 Internet Tablet running Android 2.1*

Comment: What about installing "TTS Service Extended"? Does that do anything for you?

Comment: Have you got the Android Market on the Archos 70? I know a lot of current tablets don't. I'm pretty sure that voice recognition and TTS need an extra download from the Market to work (Navigation definitely prompts to do this the first time you use it, and I thought voice recognition was linked).

Comment: @Bryan, I haven't tried that but I'm looking for STT not TTS so I'm not sure that's the right thing.  Google Voice Search seems to add that functionality but it isn't compatible with pre-2.2 devices.  I recall having Google Voice Search natively on my Droid when I had 2.1 and not downloading the app until 2.2 to get the enhancements.  @GAThrawn, yes I have the Market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 2.2 is now available for your device, which includes voice search:
http://archosfans.com/2010/11/30/froyo-firmware-2-0-54-for-gen8-released-2/

Comment: I forgot I asked this question.  Thanks for the answer.  I've actually upgraded already (did it the day it came out) but haven't worked out all the kinks yet to get the voice input working yet.

Comment: I haven't figured out all the kinks, either (on an Archos 43), but I figured this would get you going in the right direction if you hadn't heard of the update.

Comment: Thanks.  I really wish the forum.archosfans.com had a format like StackExchange.  I hate sifting through pages and pages of nonsense to get to the tiny bit of useful information buried deep inside a thread.

Comment: Me too.  If it's not on the main archosfans blog page, I'm probably not going to take the time to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the Google Voice Search?

If so, I think it is only available on selected countries.

Here on Brazil, it was unavailable until some weeks ago, when it was released on Android Market.

This page shows where it is available: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=170820

Comment: Nope.  Google Voice Search is an app that uses the Voice Recognition/Input service.